# Odd behavior of Pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I have written a program for some processing using pthreads. the program produces odd behavior every time i run it.
for simplicity I have commented the processing lines.the errors still occured.
that is the code (relevant part):

```
pthread_t Thread[THREAD_NUM];
pthread_barrier_t BarrierStart;
pthread_rwlock_t DebugLock;

void T2_FFT_Comp(void)
{
    int Return;
    T2_FFT_Comp_Input ThreadInput;
    Return = pthread_rwlock_init(&DebugLock,NULL);
    if (Return)
    {
        cout << endl << "Error while creating lock ";
    }
    pthread_barrier_init(&BarrierStart,NULL,THREAD_NUM);
    for(int i = 0;i < THREAD_NUM;i++)
    {
        ThreadInput.Start =  i*ThreadDataSize;                     //struct is relevant to processing part
        ThreadInput.ThreadNum = i;
        Return = pthread_create(&Thread[i],NULL,T2_FFT_Comp_ThreadFn,(void *)&ThreadInput);
        pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&DebugLock);
        cout << endl << "creating thread number " << i;
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&DebugLock);
        if (Return)
        {
            cout << endl << "Error while creating thread #" << i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++)
    {
        Return = pthread_join(Thread[i],NULL);
        if (Return)
        {
            pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&DebugLock);
            cout << endl << "Error while joining thread Number : " << i;
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&DebugLock);
        }
    }
    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&DebugLock);
    return;
}

void *T2_FFT_Comp_ThreadFn(void *input)
{
    int InputStart = ((T2_FFT_Comp_Input *)input)->Start;
    int ThreadID = ((T2_FFT_Comp_Input *)input)->ThreadNum;
    int Return;
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&DebugLock);
    cout << endl << "Thread number : " << ThreadID << " created";
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&DebugLock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

the program produces odd behavior. sometimes it is Segmentation Fault. some times it generates output like this

```
creating thread number 0
Thread number :0 created
creating thread number 1
creating thread number 2
creating thread number 3
Joining Thread Number : 0
Thread number :3 created
Thread number :3 created
Thread number :3 created
```

the numbers of created threads are sometimes right or wrong. also sometimes there are maultiple joining lines.
I Dont understand why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address of the same local variable, named `ThreadInput`, is passed to each thread. This means each thread is accessing, unsynchronized, the same variable. This is a race condition and is undefined behaviour. Even if it was not a race condition it is not the intended behaviour. To correct, pass different instances to each thread instead of the same one (by using an array of `T2_FFT_Comp_Input[THREAD_NUM]` and passing the address of an element to one thread only or by dynamically allocating a `T2_FFT_Comp_Input` and passing it to the thread and having the thread `free()` it).